# FuelPHP site using 10x more memory on remote server

Tags: php, fuelphp

I'm building a website using the FuelPHP framework, which by default prints the execution time and memory usage at the bottom of the page. Now I just noticed that on my local machine, I have a pretty small memory footprint:

```
Page rendered in 0.0304s using 0.721mb of memory.
```

I deployed exactly this site (including a snapshot of the database) to my remote test server and suddenly memory usage increases by a factor of 10:

```
Page rendered in 0.0963s using 7.099mb of memory.
```

I cannot explain such a big difference from the details of execution alone, so I think the deviation must be in the environment.
Unfortunately I'm mainly a programmer, not really a server admin, so I don't really know where to start looking. So I'm going to ask a bit of a general question, which will hopefully give me some useful pointers: where should I start looking? The code is exactly the same and as far as I am aware both machines (local laptop and remote server) are fairly standard Apache installations with PHP5. Any answers suggesting specific Apache or PHP settings that might cause this, or specific lines to search for in the logs, are welcome.

I realise this is a pretty general question that might get me some downvotes, any constructive critisism is welcomed instead. Basically, I'm at a loss where to even start looking, at the moment.

*Update:* I decided to first exclude the framework as the culprit, so I ran the following one-line script on both machines:

Locally I get a value of about 115, while the remote server reports about 600.

*Update 2*: Just noticed I'm running PHP5.5 locally but server is only at 5.3. Maybe some bug that got fixed later - will upgrade that first.

Comment: same os local and remote?

Comment: server/php configuration? On a side note, they use a lot of statics, usually means bad framework. The weird memory usage sort of confirms that. I recommend you to take a look at Symfony2 or Zend Framework 2 instead.

Comment: @Dagon almost, running Ubuntu 13.10 locally, while server is running 12.04 LTS version.

Comment: @Anyone, yes, possibly, but where to start? I can hardly diff the whole apache directory, right? Any particular files or settings you would have me look at? The "which framework to use" discussion is an interesting one, but I just made a long-and-hard-thought-through decision to go with this one. Maybe we can have that discussion in another topic though.

Comment: Have you tried http://serverfault.com/?

Comment: Find out which script and later - which code part/block exactly consumes a lot of memory. Then you'll know the source and it'll be easier to fix it

Comment: @MonkeyZeus do you think the question is better suited there? Because I'm happy to have it moved there if you feel it's more appropriate.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the framework's fault (at least, not all of it). See the update in the original post.

Comment: Correct, but I see you've figured it out already so I'm glad you were able to solve it!

Comment: @Anyone: Interesting. Replying to a suspected memory issue with "use Zend or Symphony"... And please elaborate why you think a static interface on the default instance means a "bad framework"? Have you ever used it? Or even looked at it?

Comment: http://r.je/static-methods-bad-practice.html Having 7 years of experience with several programming languages, I can tell you that I know why static is bad. Google for yourself if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions guys, I fixed the problem.
As noted in the update to the original post, I realised I was running PHP5.5 locally but server was only at 5.3. After some ppa-magic with `apt` and some help from other questions on SO I managed to install Apache 2.4 with PHP 5.5.x. Now I actually see

```
Page rendered in 0.0261s using 0.582mb of memory.
```

locally and remotely

```
Page rendered in 2.3184s using 1.238mb of memory.
```

Assuming that a factor 2 is caused by the server being 64-bit and not my development machine, I can live with the remaining difference.

Comment: Why does your remote server take two orders of magnitude longer to generate the page? I think you need to investigate further with Xdebug

Comment: Yeah, I also found some caching issues. Got it down to the same order of magnitude now.

Comment: Could be disk io. If it's really a server it could very well be a slow RPM server HDD vs an SSD locally.

Answer (score 1):

Use Xdebug to find out what functions are using all your memory.

Most likely it's a bug or design flaw in the framework.

It can be difficult or even impossible to get Xdebug working depending on your server. But sometimes it's pre-installed and simple.

Comment: Thanks Abhi. The immediate problem is solved, but I will look into installing Xdebug and going through the framework sometime, to see if I can find any weird things and maybe squeeze out some more performance. At the moment my priority is finishing development and testing though.